# Why is MySQL select returning different result for the same value depending if it is quoted

Tags: mysql, select, quoting

While querying my table of products like this:

```
SELECT product_id FROM products WHERE product_id = 1701114;
```

I get two rows as a result: 1701114 and 1701114B.

But after adding single quotation marks like this:

```
SELECT product_id FROM products WHERE product_id = '1701114';
```

I get expected single row result.

`product_id` column is a primary key of `VARCHAR` type and unquoted value is a digital which may be the cause, but it's quite surprising that equality sign suddenly changes to something like 'LIKE'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column `product_id` is a varchar column. It is a very bad idea to compare it to an integer (`1701114`) rather than to a string (`'1701114'`).

What happens is that MySQL silently converts the `product_id` values to numbers in order to compare them with `1701114`. `'1701114B'` is no number and should not be convertable to number, but raise an error, in my opinion. However, the MySQL developers have decided to convert it nonetheless starting from left to right and going as far as possible. So they convert `'1701114B'` to `1701114`, hence the unexpected match.

Comment: In my opinion searched number value (after WHERE) should be converted to column type (which is VARCHAR) and not the other way around - that would give expected results.

Comment: Compliant to the standard, the DBMS doesn't care whether one of the two operands is a column or not. It just compares two values and if the data types don't match it converts if possible. You compare a number with a string and one would expect 1701114 to match '1701114' (of course), but also to match '01701114' which represents the same number. So the DBMS has to convert the string to number to do the numeric comparision needed here. The only flaw in my opinion is that '1701114B' simply is no number (at least not a decimal number), so the conversion should fail with an error.

Answer (score 1):

`product_id` is a string in your table. But `1701114` is an integer. Now what does the DB do? It casts the string from the table into a  number to make the comparison.

To do that MySQL starts from left to right of the string and takes all digits and turns them into a number. The rest is cut off.

So `'1701114B'` gets converted into the number `1701114`.

The second query compares 2 strings and no conversion is necessary.